# send email (with GET params) from another php file

Tags: php, email

I have defined an email function in file: wel1.php

I need to call it in the middle of another php file, I'm trying to call it with:

```
 include 'bienvenido/wel1.php?to="'.user.'"&pass="'.pass.'"';
```

I can correctly send email if I just type this in my browser's address bar:

```
 bienvenido/wel1.php?to=some_email@gmail.com&pass=password
```

What am I missing?

Regards.

Comment: Try: `include 'bienvenido/wel1.php?to="'.$user.'"&pass="'.$pass;`

Comment: dude, if you include it then the variables are already available to the script!

Comment: You are not supposed to use an include to pass variables. Why dont you do a simple header location instead?

Comment: @RickRoy, thanks. It is because I needed to do some other stuff after calling the email function.

Comment: @JavierS I understand you found the solution but what you are trying to do can be done in the proper way using threading, use multi-threading to achieve it. Maybe if you have time and want to play around it a bit you could modify your code :)

Comment: Didn't knew php can use multi threading, but sounds good. Will google some to have a look on it, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't pass GET parameters like this.
Thanks to the same variable scope used for included files, you can simply set $_GET variable before inclusion. Like this:

```
$_GET['to'] = $user;
$_GET['pass'] = $pass;
include 'bienvenido/wel1.php";
```

You will get what you want

Comment: Thank you, it works that way. Otherwise php complaints about not being able to open file.

Comment: this answer is wrong! flat out wrong because it fosters bad practice. the variable should already be available to the script at this point as `$user` and `$pass`

Comment: Hello, both variables are there already (got them from POST). The thing is that they need to be passed to another function, so if it's still worng please let me know your proposal, regards.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't understand your mean. Plz describe the problem more!

Answer (score 0):

Dollar signs for your variables:

```
include 'bienvenido/wel1.php?to="'.$user.'"&pass="'.$pass.'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the $ in front of the variable name: $user and $pass

So try: `include 'bienvenido/wel1.php?to="'.$user.'"&pass="'.$pass.'"';`